# IE 11 not showing my module in the debugger and not downloading imported modules

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-11

When I run my website in **Firefox** or **Chrome**, it does download and show me all my modules and the modules imported by them in the debugger.

**Firefox Developer Tools:**

[image]

But when I run my website in **IE 11**, I see in the **Network** tab of the **Developer Tools** that it does *download* my module that I included in the main page, but then it does not download any of the imported modules.

**In My Main HTML Page**

```
<script src = "/Scripts/my/sathyaish.js" type="module"></script>
```

**IE Downloads My Main JS Module File**

[image]

Also, it does not show me any of my scripts in the **Debugger**.

[image]

As a result, my website doesn't work on IE at all.

Why isn't IE downloading the ES 6 module imports and why won't it show me my scripts in the debugger?

Comment: IE11 doesn't support ES6 (you need to target ES5 for IE). Are you using a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)?

Comment: No, just plain old JavaScript with some jQuery. That's terrible. IE 11 doesn't support even CSS variables. I spent 3 hours changing my code because I was using CSS variables. IE seems not to support anything interesting.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 according to Microsoft's Security chief IE is not a browser - https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/  Probably why it doesn't support anything a normal browser does :(

Comment: As a tip for all developers, define which browser support is needed before start coding, so you make sure it support that level, and then add [_progressive enhancement_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Browser ES Module Loader to load the related modules.

Add the following script reference in the header:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/browser-es-module-loader/dist/babel-browser-build.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/browser-es-module-loader"></script>
```

Note: please keep the order, and the bluebird.min.js reference is used to solve the "'promise' is undefined" error.